# How to prevent CMD key in Parallels Desktop 9 from switching to Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: parallels-desktop

Very annoying: I am running PD in Coherence mode and work in Visual Studio. If I press CMD, the Windows start screen appears. 
Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ha! Found it!

```
PD Settings -> Shortcuts -> Virtual Machines -> Windows 8
```

then map CMD to CTRL:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Parallels, go to Preferences --> Shortcuts --> System Shortcuts and set Send System Shortcuts on: to "Always"

Comment: Doesn't work. Sorry.